# Cannot change value of global variable inside a function

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I created a method inside home.page.ts to retrieve json from AirVisual API and will parse specific data to home.page.html

However, It looks like that the code in function () doesn't assign any value to the global variable.

```
export class HomePage {

  constructor() { }

  aqi: string;

  getAQI() {
    var value;
    var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
    r.responseType = 'json';
    r.open('GET', "http://api.airvisual.com/v2/city?city=Bang%20Rak&state=Bangkok&country=Thailand&key=30c3e5bd-32d3-4fdb-b2dd-fe36928850b5", true);
    r.onload = function () {
      var jsonResponse = r.response;
      value = parseInt(jsonResponse.data.current.pollution.aqius);
      console.log(value); // This print the value from JSON
    }
    r.send();
    console.log(value); // This print undefined in console
    this.aqi = String(value);
  }
```

Since `value` outside the function is undefined, So is `aqi`. Thus, I can't use it on my html page.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting an event handler for .onload, but your getAQI function will continue local execution after r.send() and run the very next line.  Since onload hasn't happened and been handled yet, it is still undefined. onload() will happen after that.  If you put breakpoints inside the onload function and on the console.log line you should see the order of execution.

Comment: Oh I see, so how I get the value out of that function to apply it to global variable. I cannot change ```aqi``` in r.onload() scope and I also cannot change ```aqi``` after r.send() because r.onload() don't get executed yet.

Comment: you are getting value out of that function and applying it to the (not global but scoped) variable.  It works, you just need to setTimeout() and check back after onload runs.